# Is there a name for the integral used to define square integrable functions?

Tags: notation

A square integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ would be defined as a function $f(\mathbf{x})$ satisfying the constraint
$$
\int |f(\mathbf{x})|^2 d^n\mathbf{x} < \infty,
$$
for $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Is there a specific name given to the quantity
$$
\int |f(\mathbf{x})|^2 d^n\mathbf{x}?
$$

Comment: Isn't that the $\ell_2$ norm for $f$ or or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the square of a quantity normally called the $2$-norm, or the [$L^2$-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces). As its name suggests, it is a norm on the space of square-integrable functions, which is called $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: ... the *square* of the $L^2$-norm, the norm itself is given by 
$$ \|f\|_{L^2} = \left(\int_{\mathbf R^n} |f(x)|^2\, dx\right)^{1/2} $$

Comment: @martini Fair point...

Comment: @martini Good spot!